# Display Image in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to display a image which retrieved from MySQL databases, I received the image successfully but how to display it on Bowser

I get the image in Eloquent, it show me the name of photo in Database not the real data, so I go to Blade and set

> {{Form::open($file, array('files'=> true))}}

but it show me "Ca not display image because it contains Errors"

Comment: How your image stored in MysqlDB? Is it in a Blob field or it is just URL of image?

Comment: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?= base64_encode($blob) ?>" width="200" height="300">

Answer (score 0):

in controller file write this function:

```
public function showimage($id){
    $pr = DB::table('products')->where('id', $id)->first();
    $response['img'] =$pr->img;//blob file
    $response['type']=$pr->image_type;
    return View::make('products.show', compact('response'));
}
```

and in the view file type this:

```html
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
<h1>show</h1>


  <img src="data:{{$response['type']}};base64,{{$response['img']}}" />

@stop
```